# Handle Chrome default pop up through selenium web-driver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am working on automation test-case through selenium web-driver. I am stuck at one place where I am always getting first chrome'd default pop up. I am not able to do anything with that pop up as it's not inspecting in code, Please check in attached screen shot for default pop-up.

Please suggest me to handle these thing. Any help is appreciated.

[image: chrome default pop up SS]

Comment: Here, `Do Nothing` button is focused. Whenever this appears, can't you `sendkeys()` `enter` ?

Comment: If windowHandle doesn't help, then there is no better solution from selenium. this link might help [http://www.coderexception.com/CBN6BzBNUiWXQyUx/is-there-a-chrome-switch-to-suppress-external-protocol-request]

Comment: vignesh,I removed the perticular app from local state file as suggested in link, but this doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

These are Window based pop up, which is not controlled by selenium so need to use java.awt.Robot class or Autoit tool.
Robot class describe as-
for example:

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.delay(1000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
    robot.delay(10000);
```

it takes one key at a time, we can not pass multiple keys at one time.
Hope this will solve your problem.